# How to set a correct $content_width when there are two content widths on one page?

Tags: theme-development, content-width

Currently I have 1860px wide image as featured image which shows on top of a post page, and 800px as post content width, and when I

**Set $content_width = 800**

The featured image shows as 800px wide only

**Set $content_width = 1860**

Featured image shows well, but embedded youtube video shows as 1860 x 1077, I tried to set `max-width:100%` on iframe, it fixed the width, but height still 1077, a `height:auto` has no effect.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can set iframe tag with **width:100%** 

Let say you have the following structure

```
<div class='video'>
     iframe tag here    
</div>
<style>
.video iframe {
    width: 100%; // this will automatically adjust the height
}
</style>
```

Comment: Same to "max-width:100%", the iframe generated by WordPress have attributes of width="1860" and height="1077", height doesn't change

Comment: Could you please share site url of that ?